# java templating How do I explicitly specify to use a parameter variable over an already named class?

Tags: java, generics

```
public abstract class InterruptableEvaluator<State> {
    public abstract evaluate(State state);
    public abstract haltEvaluation();

    private final class EvaluationThread extends Thread {
        private State state;

        public EvaluationThread(State state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            evaluate(state);
            haltEvaluation();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem lies here:

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            evaluate(state);
            haltEvaluation();
        }
```

the object `state` is being treated as a `java.lang.Thread.State` object, instead of using the parameter from `InterruptableEvaluator`.

How do I explicitly tell Java to use the parameter variable instead of `java.lang.Thread.State`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics usually contain single letters for type parameters for brevity and due to the lack of true classes that are named with single letters. Change `State` to `S` or any other valid type name that isn't an existing class/interface in the parameter and everywhere it's used and you should be fine.

Comment: Is there really no other way to specify the use of the type variable State over the class State? I'd like to keep the use of the longer name simply because it makes the code this is in far less ambiguous. The S type variable is in use elsewhere in the code, and picking other letters or adding numbers like S1 just make the code god awful to read. This is a problem within a much larger project.

Comment: @Axoren Unfortunately no way. `ParamState` perhaps?

Comment: That is unfortunate. I'll have to see about how to rename the parameters, then. `State` was so perfect everywhere else in the codebase.

Comment: @Axoren You can use anything that is not recognized as a class.

Comment: A refactor may possibly work depending on how your IDE tries to toy with the library name.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell Does that meet java naming conventions?

Comment: Would I be able to just add a parameter variable to EvaluationThread like so: `EvaluationThread<S extends State>` and then use S within the Thread class? This would allow me to use the State parameter in the rest of the codebase AND within the InterruptibleEvaluator class without bringing new names into the mix. Really, the only problem is within Thread subclasses. Would I be doing anything wrong using `S extends State`?

Comment: @Axoren Try it and see. I'm not at an IDE at the moment, so I'll check when I can if you need me to.

Comment: Consider that naming generic parameters as single letters is the standard and although it may *seem* harder to read now, others already find it easier with a single letter and in time you will too. Also, it becomes actually quite *confusing* if the generic param looks like a class name, because readers of your code may not realise it's a generic parameter when used. Better to stay with the standard.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the parameter `State` to another name everywhere in the code base, I believe I've found a solution that works:

```
public abstract class InterruptableEvaluator<State> {
    public abstract evaluate(State state);
    public abstract haltEvaluation();

    private final class EvaluationThread<S extends State> extends Thread {
        private S state;

        public EvaluationThread(S state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            evaluate(state);
            haltEvaluation();
        }
    }
}
```

This way, it's still very obvious that the variable in the evaluation thread is a State object and the change from `State` to `S` is local to this one class definition. This means no crazy refactoring sprees across my whole codebase while still disambiguating between `State` and `java.lang.Thread.State`.

However, it would be nice if Java provided an easier way to avoid this issue.